# Is the Riemann Sphere a submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

This feels like a stupid question, but I am missing some imagination here.

Anyway, I know that the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ is a one-dimensional complex manifold and that I can also view it as a 2-sphere embedded as a real submanifold into $\mathbb{R}^3$.

However, is the Riemann sphere also an (immersed or embedded?) one-dimensional complex submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Somehow, since $\mathbb{C}^2$ has one (real) dimension more than $\mathbb{R}^3$, I feel it should work. Does it?

What about a (one-dimensional complex) Torus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no compact complex analytic submanifolds $M$ in $\mathbb C^n$ (except for points), since the coordinate functions $(z_1, \cdots z_n)$ restrict to complex analytic functions on it, which has to be constant as $M$ is compact.

Comment: Well, there are complex analytic submanifolds in $\mathbb{C}^n$, but they are all of dimension zero.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Edited. ${}{}$

Comment: Sorry, I don't yet understand. I have the coordinate functions $z_i$ each mapping $M$ into $\mathbb{C}$ analytically. Why are those constant? Can you apply Liouvilles Theorem somehow?

Comment: Something like that @TheAbelian, I am thinking of the [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle).

Comment: Can you explain how to do that? I don't see how to find that a coordinate function needs to take a maximum inside its domain (which can be a small open subset of M, right?). Probably I need to use compactness of M, but I don't know how.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi there can well be non-compact complex submanifolds of positive dimension in $\mathbb{C}^n$, right?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  it sounded like he would need compactness in his proof (which unfortunately I still don't understand), so I assumed that there might be non-compact complex submanifolds.

Comment: @TheAbelian Oh sorry I misread your comment I thought you said "compact" instead of "non-compact"... Yes you can have non-compact submanifold, for example $\mathbb{C}^n$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^n$, similarly $\mathbb{C}^m$ embeds in $\mathbb{C}^n$ when $m < n$.

Comment: By coordinate function I mean the one on $\mathbb C^n$ (that is, $(z_1, \cdots z_n) \mapsto z_i$). Just restrict these functions to $M$, the compactness of $M$ implies that $|z_i|$ attains a maximum, but this is impossible since they are holomorphic functions. @TheAbelian